# Zero or one quantifier (`?`) does not seem to be greedy

Tags: python, regex

Given these two test strings:

```
'eitherxory.'
'justy.'
```

I would like to match 'x' (or nothing, if 'x' is not present) and 'y', respectively:

```
('x', 'y')
(None, 'y')
```

The pattern I've come up with is `(x)?.*?(y)` but the matches are:

```
(None, 'y')
(None, 'y')
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Python (`import re; re.search(pattern, line).groups()`) but the question is actually generic.

Comment: Why not capture *not `x`* (`[^x]`) rather than *anything* (`.`)? See e.g. https://regex101.com/r/dO6eV7/1

Comment: The reason for this behaviour is that the regex engine backtracks one subexpression (if I can call it like that) at a time before backtracking to the one before for efficiency. Let me know if you want me to elaborate more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use:

```
(?:(x).*)?(y)
```

We only want to match `.*` if we have found `x`, so we can group them together and move the optional quantifier outside. This avoids the case when `.*` eats up all the characters from the start of the string.

Keep in mind that this won't work if `x` occurs after `y` in the string. For that you could use something like this:

```
(?=.*(x)).*(y)
```

Comment: Nailed it. In my case, I can guarantee `x` always comes before `y`, but I loved seeing how the lookahead operator can be used in the other case, too.